# Purpose of Remote Service + android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I need some help in understanding when and why to use Remote Service instead of local service. There are several cases where one can use a local service. For example: playing music in background, downloading files from network without interrupting the user. But i am unable to found a similar use case scenarios where i have to use Remote Service.

I am very curious about the scenarios where one can use Remote Services.

Any help is appreciated. I dont wanna know how to implement it. I know the technical part on how to implement it, do the interprocess communication. All i want to know is when to use this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote services are used when different applications need to communicate with said service.  Having a service that, say, tracks your location, can be accessed from multiple applications using remote services.

Comment: so when do we(general developers) write these global services.. You give the example of location tracking -- this service is written by Android team and we use this to get the location. So is there any scenario, where we have to right such kind of service. Any example which does the same.

Comment: Here's an example: I write a service that tracks the phase of the moon. Any application can query that service and request the current moon phase. An application could also request the service to call it back when the moon phase changes. This service has a public API that any other Android application could use.

Comment: You can also use a remote service to extend the upper memory limits of an application. Sometimes you have an application that is bigger than the maximum process size allows. You can split the process into 2 processes by putting a lot of data and business logic in the service process and do all the UI with Activities in the UI process. This is another reason to use a remote service.